# hidden background image in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an edit button which appears on the page when users have access to edit. I've implemented it as a link:

```
<a class='editlink' href='edit.html'></a>
```

My corresponding css renders the editlink class as a pencil icon:

```
.editlink{
 background-image: url(../img/pencil.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

This works fine in Firefox, but doesn't appear at all in IE. If I put an & nbsp; inside the `<a>` tag then it shows the pencil, but I was hoping to keep the  tag empty. Is there a modification I can make to the CSS to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug again related to the hasLayout property in IE.

Try adding

```
zoom:1;
```

to your style and it should work fine.

Comment: and all of a sudden my entire site works in IE. This solved it perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! Better keep this hasLayout thing in memory. It will more likely than not show up again one day or the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite a common problem in IE. Even table cells with no content fail to actually render or appear in the document. It's very normal. My advice to you would be to keep the space in there or to make the link "display:block;" and then use width and height to make it bigger or smaller. This has it's own problems associated with positioning, as it will no longer be an inline element.

One solid alternative would be to take the link and do the following to it:

```
<a class='editlink' href='edit.html'><img src="img/pencil.png"></a>
```

This would ensure it stretches the anchor correctly in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. The reason we can't do the <img> tag is that requires our code generating the link to know the path where the image is located. Barring any other solutions, I'll probably go with the space option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width and a height on the link in your stylesheet.  This renders correctly in FF, IE, and Chrome:
`.editlink{
 background-image: url(../img/pencil.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding: 2px 8px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 20px;
}`